# Rails Mask subdomain URL issue with Post Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, masking

I am trying to mask my shopify url as `www.mywebsite.com/store`. I want people to be able to use the shopify site as usually just with the mask of 'www.mywebsite.com/store/*path/`

I am using a rails app and I have got the basics working, but it is only working for GET requests. How can I handle POST requests? Or, a bit less ideal, but is there a way I can escape the masking when it encounters a POST request?

This is my store action:

```
  def store
    path = params[:path].to_s
    source_url = 'https://mystore.myshopify.com/' + path
    source_content_type = ''
    source_body = open(source_url) do |f|
      source_content_type = f.content_type     # "text/html"
      f.read
    end
    if source_content_type == 'text/html'
      output_base = request.base_url + '/store'
      output_body = source_body.gsub(/\b(href|src|rel)="\/\//, '\1="https:\/\/')
      output_body = output_body.gsub(/\b(href|src|rel)="\//, '\1="' + output_base + '/')
      output_body = output_body.gsub(/\b(href|src|rel)="http:\/\/mystore\.myshopify\.com/, '\1="/store')
    else
      output_body = source_body
    end

    render :text => output_body, :content_type => source_content_type, :layout => false
  end
```

And this is my routes:

```
  get "/store" => "blog#store"
  get "/store/*path" => "blog#store"
```

Comment: Both those routes are sending 'get' requests.  You need to provide a "post" request in your routes or it will be asking for data instead.

Comment: What is the best way to do that? I tried adding   `post "/store" => "blog#store" post "/store/*path" => "blog#store"`
 but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Where is the form you want them to provide info to your site?  More specifically what is the name of the view file?  And what action in your controller do you expect to handle it?  Give me those and I'll show you.

Comment: I actually don't want to be handling any of the data or need any input from them. I only want to mask the url of my shopify shop as www.mywebsite.com/store . Shopify should handle all their data.

Comment: An example when the problem occurs comes when the user wants to add an item to their cart in the store. While the masking works until then, when they click add to cart, a POST request, I get the error `No route matches [POST] "/cart/add"`. I understand that I need to add POST routing to handle these so that the application knows to send that data back to the shopify url but I cant seem to figure out how. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: If it's working for get requests try this route:  match '/store' => "blog#store", via: [:get, :post]
This assumes the route url /store is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84568/discussion-between-brian-kunzig-and-macgill4444).